# String Array Expecting Declaration?

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, class, member-initialization

I'm hitting the following issue in this simple code:

```
Public Class BookStoreDatabase

Public publicationArray(0 To 3) As String

publicationArray(0) = "Stories to Scare People With"
End Class
```

The bit "publicationArray(0) etc" is telling me that a declaration for "publicationArray" is expected. This seems like it shouldn't be happening.

Comment: question? what do you mean VB6 with an IDE of visual studio 2012 which doesn't support vb6 only vb.net

Comment: That's my mistake. I meant vb.net on Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Your assignment needs to be in a method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign a array element at `Class` level. If you need it to be assigned as soon as the `BookStoreDatabase` class itself is instantiated, you must use a constructor:

```
Public Class BookStoreDatabase

    Public Sub New()
        publicationArray(0) = "Stories to Scare People With"
    End Sub

    Public publicationArray(0 To 3) As String

End Class
```

Comment: That did it, thank you so much. A lot of tutorials and online resources didn't make that clear but this makes sense.